# Why can't I click the left side of the link on this CSS flip card in Chrome?

Tags: html, css, webkit, css-transforms

Attempting to click the *left* side of the link on the back of this flip card does not work in Chrome. Yet, when I mouse over the *right* side of the link, I see the pointer cursor and am able to interact with it:

```css
/* prefixed by https://autoprefixer.github.io (PostCSS: v7.0.26, autoprefixer: v9.7.3) */

.card {
  -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
  perspective: 1000px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.card .card-inner {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s;
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s;
  -o-transition: transform 0.6s;
  transition: transform 0.6s;
  transition: transform 0.6s, -webkit-transform 0.6s;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  will-change: transform;
}

.card .card-inner .card-face {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.card .card-inner .card-face.card-back {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  transform: rotateY( 180deg);
}

.card .card-inner .card-face .card-face-inner .card-face-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.card:hover .card-inner {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  transform: rotateY( 180deg);
}

.card .card-back {
  background: steelblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-inner">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x500?text=%20" alt="" />

    <div class="card-face card-front">
      <div class="card-face-inner">
        <div class="card-face-content">
          Front
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card-face card-back">
      <div class="card-face-inner">
        <div class="card-face-content">
          <a href="#foo">Back</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I fix this so the entire link is clickable? I'm guessing this has something to do with `backface-visibility`. I came across [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13324187/5749974), but I think the solution is already implemented here with the lines:

```
.card .card-inner {
    ...
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the **reason** but this is most likely a bug because it works on Firefox as intended. Adding `pointer-events: none;` to `.card-inner` and `pointer-events: auto` to `.card-face` works, only god knows why.

```css
/* prefixed by https://autoprefixer.github.io (PostCSS: v7.0.26, autoprefixer: v9.7.3) */

.card {
  -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
  perspective: 1000px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.card .card-inner {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s;
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s;
  -o-transition: transform 0.6s;
  transition: transform 0.6s;
  transition: transform 0.6s, -webkit-transform 0.6s;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  will-change: transform;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.card .card-inner .card-face {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.card .card-inner .card-face.card-back {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  transform: rotateY( 180deg);
}

.card .card-inner .card-face .card-face-inner .card-face-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.card:hover .card-inner {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  transform: rotateY( 180deg);
}

.card .card-back {
  background: steelblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-inner">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x500?text=%20" alt="" />

    <div class="card-face card-front">
      <div class="card-face-inner">
        <div class="card-face-content">
          Front
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card-face card-back">
      <div class="card-face-inner">
        <div class="card-face-content">
          <a href="#foo">Back</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Interesting! So, I just realized that my original pen wasn't working in Safari, I was getting a weird flickering effect. Both solutions from you and @vals work, but yours somehow makes it work in Safari too!

Comment: Ended up using a combination of both of your solutions for my actual application.

Answer (score 6):

The reason is that 180deg is not exactly half a turn due to small precision errors in Chrome.

And the left side of the element is *under* the front side (even if you can't see it, it's still there).

Raise your element in the Z direction, just a pixel, and it works (now it is fully over the other side):

```css
/* prefixed by https://autoprefixer.github.io (PostCSS: v7.0.26, autoprefixer: v9.7.3) */

.card {
  -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
  perspective: 1000px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.card .card-inner {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s;
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s;
  -o-transition: transform 0.6s;
  transition: transform 0.6s;
  transition: transform 0.6s, -webkit-transform 0.6s;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  will-change: transform;
}

.card .card-inner .card-face {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.card .card-inner .card-face.card-back {
  transform: rotateY( 180deg) translateZ(1px);   /* changed */
}

.card .card-inner .card-face .card-face-inner .card-face-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.card:hover .card-inner {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  transform: rotateY( 180deg);
}

.card .card-back {
  background: steelblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-inner">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x500?text=%20" alt="" />

    <div class="card-face card-front">
      <div class="card-face-inner">
        <div class="card-face-content">
          Front
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card-face card-back">
      <div class="card-face-inner">
        <div class="card-face-content">
          <a href="#foo">Back</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I noticed that my original pen didn't work in Safari, somehow the solution that @Taylan provided worked to fix the link issue and make it work in Safari. No idea how, but both of your answers are valuable!

Comment: Happy that it helped !

Comment: I had this issue on an app since iOS version 16.4. I do not know why. My links under the flip cards worked fine on iOS until the 16.4 update. Adding the translateZ(1px) solved the problem! Many thanks